# Enconding conversion from Mac to Linux and viceversa

Tags: unicode, input-encodings

How could I use on Linux (utf-8) a previously created file on Mac using for example MacRoman as encoding and viceversa?

Comment: there is `iconv`, but this question is off-topic here and should be moved to Stackoverflow.

Comment: I think this could be useful also here Johannes_B

Comment: I think, since this obviously is intended to be useful for others (you answered yourself within a minute), you should have done a better job in writing the question. Please extend it a bit to make it on topic here.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Johannes_B I will do it as soon as possible.

Comment: If you copy the file to a Linux box and don't modify it, it will compile without any change.

Comment: It's not a solution egreg... I had some issues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [iconv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv) (iconv - Convert encoding of given files from one encoding to another)

From a terminal write:

```
iconv -f MACINTOSH -t UTF-8 source_mac.tex > destination_utf.tex
```

where **MACINTOSH** is mac encoding.

Pay also attention to inpuntec.
Let's suppose your are using under mac:

```
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
```

you have to remove it and add for example:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontec}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

If you want the viceversa you should use this command from terminal:

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t MACINTOSH source_utf8.tex > destination_mac.tex
```

than:

add:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontec}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

and remove:

```
 \usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
```

Comment: On the other hand, several editors for Mac OS X have long been able to cope with UTF-8.

Comment: Using option utf8x by default is not a good idea; it is only useful when dealing with CJK-scripts. For latin scripts, `utf8` suffices. Internally, the little x makes a *huge* difference.

Answer (score 2):

There are tools to recode a file (`iconv`, `recode`, ...), see the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252662/16967) of teoreda.

But these tools do not change the option for package `inputenc`.
Here package `selinput` helps.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{
  adieresis={ä},
  germandbls={ß},
  copyright={©},
}

\begin{document}
  Umlauts: ÄÖÜäöüß, Copyright: ©
\end{document}
```

UTF-8 encoded the `\SelectInputMapping` selects `utf8`:

```
Package selinput Info: Encoding `utf8' selected on input line 8.
```

When the file is in mac-roman encoding, the result is:

```
Package selinput Info: Encoding `x-mac-roman' selected on input line 8.
```

Encoding `x-mac-roman` comes from project [`inputenx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/inputenx), which prefers text symbol encodings. When `applemac` is preferred, the list of encodings, which uses `\SelectInputMapping` to select from, can be explicitly given before:

```
\SelectInputEncodingList{utf8,applemac}
```